# Why I can't see boxes when i plot boxplots in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to plot a boxplot in R, and I can't see the boxes, below shows what i see:

[image]

and here is the code i am writing:

```
ggplot(data=FIR,
  aes(x=as.factor(FIR$Revised.Status),y=as.numeric(FIR$Diff_Date_Requested)))+
  geom_boxplot(fill="blue", alpha=0.2)+xlab("Status")
```

`Revised.Status`: is the results of the request it is A or C

`Diff_Date_Requested`: is the difference between 2 dates

Comment: try "outlier.shape = NA"

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  please read [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

From `?geom_boxplot`:

> The lower and upper hinges correspond to the first and third quartiles
>   (the 25th and 75th percentiles).

If your 25th percentile and 75th percentile are the same value, or are really close together, you won't see the box, just a single line.

It looks like you might be working with count data or other integer values.  If more than half your y-values are 1 (i.e., whatever it is happens the next day, so difference = 1), that might explain it.

You might want to think about other ways of visualizing count data, like `geom_bar()`.